# Coupled fortran/c++ with pointer called in python gives a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: python, c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, fortran

I have a coupled code (fortran with c++) that I am now calling in python. The main.exe works fine but when I call the coupled version in python I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. I identified the line of the code that gives the problem, and apparently it is cause by a pointer. Here is my function:

```
void emissionPrimSR(pTSysRac sR)
    {
    /* Emission de nouveaux axes primaires sur le système racinaire */

    pTAxe nouvAxe;
    int numPrim, nbPrimAEmettre;
    r3 vInit, dirInit;
    double angRot,angI;

    //printf("\n EMISSION PRIM SR : postest0=%lf, postest1=%lf,postest2=%lf\n",postest0, postest1, postest2);

    nbPrimAEmettre = calcNouvNbPrim() - sR->nbPrim; /* Nombre de primaires à émettre */

    printf("nombre Adv à emettre  %d \n",nbPrimAEmettre);//---- TO DO SUPPRIME LLab

    for ((numPrim=1); (numPrim<=nbPrimAEmettre); (numPrim++)) /* Pour les nouvelles primaires à émettre */
    {
     printf("Je suis dans emissionPrimSR %3i \n",sR->nbPrim);
     /* Calcul de la direction initiale de l'axe */
     if (sR->nbPrim==0) angI=tireGaussien(0.0,0.1); // émission de la radicule qui a un gravitropisme initial fort
      else angI=tireGaussien(P_angInitMoyVertPrim,P_angInitETVertPrim); // angle par rapport à la verticale
     vInit[0]=sin(angI);
     vInit[1]=0.0;
     vInit[2]=cos(angI);
     angRot=sR->angDep+tireAngRad();
     rotZ(vInit,dirInit,angRot);

     /* Génération de l'axe et intégration dans le système racinaire */

nouvAxe=initialiseAxe(sR->nbAxeForm+1,P_diamMax,sR->origine,dirInit,NULL,NULL,postest0, postest1, postest2);
ajouteAxeSR(sR,nouvAxe);
sR->nbPrim++;
  }



  }
```

So, this line gives a segmentation fault:

```
    nbPrimAEmettre = calcNouvNbPrim() - sR->nbPrim;
```

The function calcNouvNbPrim() looks like:

```
    int calcNouvNbPrim(void){ 
     /* Calcul du nouveau nombre de primaires */

     int nouvNbPrim;

     // CB TEST printf("\n CALC NOUV NB PRIM - TEMPS = %d\n", temps);

     nouvNbPrim=int (P_vitEmissionPrim*temps);

    if (nouvNbPrim>=P_nbMaxPrim) nouvNbPrim=P_nbMaxPrim;

     return nouvNbPrim;

     }  /* Fonction calcNouvNBPrim */
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I run `gdb python` I get the following error:

```
  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  0x00007ffff1f7f2e6 in emissionPrimSR (sR=0x0) at src/ArchiSimple.cpp:1586
  1586    nbPrimAEmettre = calcNouvNbPrim() - sR->nbPrim; /* Nombre de primaires � �mettre */`
```

SOLUTION:

I had to separate my functions C++ and fortran and called them separately in Python. f90wrap is not able to deal with ISO_C_BINDING functions.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the welcome [tour]. We need to see more code. How does calcNouvNbPrim() look like? Please see [mcve].

Comment: Thank you @VladimirF for your comment and apologies for not giving a complete example. The function calcNouvNbPrim() was now added to the code.

Comment: Your debug trace shows sR is 0.  Hence the SIGSEGV.   Is sR 0 on entry or only after the call?

Comment: So @cup , I've printed sR before the function and in it, and both values are 0. sR on entry  0 
sR  after call 0

Comment: If you are using sR->nbPrim, then it should not be zero.  Check the calling routine.

Comment: Hi @cup, you are right. It shouldn't be 0x0. So, I've tested to initiate sR inside my function and it doesn't give me a segmentation fault, but it is wrong because sR shouldn't be initiated every time step, but once at the beginning. The weird thing is that when I run my .exe (c++/fortran), sR is not zero, but when I call it in my python wrapped function, sR is zero. Why is it happening?

Comment: How are you populating the structure in python and how are you calling it from python?

Comment: Are you using a swig interface or a hand wirtten PyObject interface to communicate between Python and C?

Comment: Hi @cup, I am using a function called f90wrap [https://github.com/jameskermode/f90wrap] to wrap up the code, and using f2py to make python callable functions. After that I rewrote the main in python. It should work because the c++ code is written in extern C and binded in fortran with iso_c_binding.

Comment: Please do not edit your question with a solution, post an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

I had to separate my functions C++ and fortran and called them separately in Python. f90wrap is not able to deal with ISO_C_BINDING functions.